# ServiceStack Redis Client and receive timeouts

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

We're using ServiceStack RedisClient for caching. Lately we had some network latency between Redis and our web server. We use `PooledRedisClientManager`. We noticed the following behavior when we send a command (specifically Get):

1. There's some latency in the network
2. We get a SocketIO exception:

   > Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

   The connection is still open - just slow.
3. This exception propagates all the way out to our code base, where we dispose the client (i.e. return to the pool)
4. As a result, all responses from the client will be n-1. For example:

   ```
   var x = client.Get<string>(id1); //this fails for latency. x = ""
   //network restored
   var y = client.Get<string>(id2); //y = value(id1)
   var z = client.Get<string>(id3); //z = value(id2)
   var w = client.Increment(id4); //fails for 'unexpected token' since it gets value(id3)
   ```

Anyone else encountered this issue? How did you resolve it?

Comment: Hi Amir, did you get this issue resolved?

Comment: @richardwhatever - we wrapped ServiceStack client with a proxy class to catch all exceptions, and then just set the 'HadExceptions' flag